# How to log into web site using uiwebview with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to try to log into a web page using UIWebView in an ios applicaiton. However, I do not know how can I  do this. I am showing web site with

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://m.falalem.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I want to log into this page using my username and password parameter.
Login Page -> http://m.falalem.com/Login
After login page -> http://m.falalem.com/User-Info

How can log into this page using uiwebview??
Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logging into a webpage in general (using JS, PHP, etc.) uses a `POST` request, right?

Specifically on your website, for the user `hello` with the password `world` the `POST` looks like the following:

http://m.falalem.com/System/Falalem?LoginUser=c7e28a618886dba19eac0892ad90cf51&RTrn=http%3A%2F%2Fm.falalem.com%2FUser-Info&EPostam=hello&Sifrem=world

where your specific request headers are:

```
LoginUser: c7e28a618886dba19eac0892ad90cf51
RTrn: http://m.falalem.com/User-Info
EPostam (user): hello
Sifrem (password): world
```

Likewise, in Swift, you're going to load a `UIWebView` with a similar request. Presumably, you are receiving the username and password from `UITextField`s and are going to use them to login to a `UIWebView`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

// Note: you will want to secure this either by checking the box 
// in Attributes Inspector or programmatically using 
// `passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = true`
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

...

// fire when the UIButton for "sign in" or "Giriş Yap" is pressed
@IBAction func signIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://m.falalem.com/System/Falalem")

    // Note that you will want to use a `NSMutableURLRequest` 
    // because otherwise, you will not be able to edit the `request.HTTPMethod`
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // You need to specifically tell the request what HTTP method to use
    // (e.g., GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Is this generated/an API key? If generated per user, use `var`
    let loginUser: String = "c7e28a618886dba19eac0892ad90cf51"

    // The page you want to go to after login
    let redirectPage: String = "http://m.falalem.com/User-Info"

    // Get the user's credentials from the `UITextField`s
    var username: String = usernameTextField.text
    var password: String = passwordTextField.text

    // Concatenating everything together
    var userCredentials: String = "EPostam=\(username)&Sifrem=\(password)"
    var bodyData: String = "\(userCredentials)&RTrn=\(redirectPage)&LoginUser=\(loginUser)"

    // Encode the bodyData string into a 
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    // load the UIWebView `webView` with this request
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Now, if you're not getting the user's credentials via `UITextField`s, you can simply proceed with

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://m.falalem.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

because the user will then just input his/her credentials via the mobile website and be redirected that way.

Lastly, you'll probably want to use SSL because otherwise you're sending the password (or the hash) over as plain text, which is not secure.

Comment: I solved this problem but you are also right. Thank you for your answer @michael-recachinas.

Comment: @EmreBEGEN did you solve it a different way? I'd love to hear how! Also, no problem. :)