# How can I know the HTTP protocol of arbitary website?

Tags: ios, swift, jsp, swift2

I'm trying to login to "http://students.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/index.jsp" using swift.

I found a question about this in stackoverflow.

[How to log into web site using uiwebview with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653480/how-to-log-into-web-site-using-uiwebview-with-swift)

But how can I know that "RTrn" or "EPostam" or "LoginUser" stuff?

Comment: Open the web-page in your browser, and then use the "View Source" option of your browser to see what the web-page actually does.