# What's the simplest way to login to a website in swift 4

Tags: swift, authentication, web

I have found other answers to this question on this site, but they seem to be either outdated or not especially descriptive. I am rather unexperienced in website access using swift so code would be greatly appreciated.

If I already have the username and password, how do I log into a website, for example this one, using swift code.

This other SA question seems to solve the problem well: [How to log into web site using uiwebview with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653480/how-to-log-into-web-site-using-uiwebview-with-swift)

Comment: You wouldn't generally just 'login to a website' if the website has an API you can use that

Answer (score 0):

The way I am trying to solve this issue is by creating a new View Controller and adding a Web View on to it with access to the website. There's a post here [Get HTML from WKWebview in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751860/get-html-from-wkwebview-in-swift) that could help as you are using Swift, but without any detailing of your code this issue can't be solved completely. My solution is a bit unorthodox and frankly "bad coding", but it should *in theory* function well and I have seen other responses which do it similarly. Also, I would revise your question and try to make it more formal/informative so everyone could have a better chance at helping you out.

Good Luck!

**Edit: Reviewing a different response**

The easiest way to do this as mentioned by one of your comments would be to see if the Website you are using has an API. I used a course on Udemy which explained their functionalities if you need one. I would recommend looking at the Cocoa Pod Alamofire and seeing if it could help you (perhaps in conjunction with SwiftyJSON).

Side note:
The reason why I am not using Alamofire for my project (one similar to yours) is because I could not find an accessible API.